# What's the name of this font used in this figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, idl-programming-language

[image: font name?]

I want to use this font in matplotlib plotting, but I can not find out the name. Does anyone know?

This figure is got by IDL plotting on Mac OS (10.9) like:

```
filename = 'name.eps'
myDevice = !D.NAME
SET_PLOT,'ps'
DEVICE,DECOMPOSED=1,ENCAPSULATED=1,/COLOR,FILENAME=filename

......

DEVICE, /CLOSE
SET_PLOT, myDevice
```

Comment: This doesn't look like something you want programming expertise to answer. Try a [font identifier](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), or if that doesn't work, ask the [graphic design guys](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: +1 for ask elsewhere. If I had to guess, maybe Futura or Century Gothic. Definitely some geometric-sans font.

Comment: ^_^ sorry, I didn't know there is a 'Graphic Design' section. Thank you guys for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a font expert, but this looks a lot to me like the font that was used with pen plotters.  Looking around for "pen plotter font", turns up ["Hershey Vector Font"](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/), which looks quite close.

[image]

Comment: You are right, thanks! It reminds me that I have seen the word 'Hershey' before in the IDL documentation. I'll try to find out whether I can use it in my python plotting.

Comment: It seems that there's a TrueType font similar to the Hershey vector font, called RomanS.ttf and RomanD.ttf.  Once you have that, it's not too hard to get matplotlib to use the selected font.

Comment: I've found RomanS and RomanD. It's great! I guess, in terms of plotting, they are better than Hershey vector font which is created very early (actually I can not find how to use Hershey vector font...). Thank you so much! @tom10

Answer (score 3):

The font is indeed a Hershey vector font: Hershey Simplex Light. This [user](https://github.com/scruss/AVHershey-OTF) on Github has the font definition files (otf) that you can copy/clone into your system and set as the default fonts in your matplotlibrc. Not all the characters are included, but you can use [fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io/) to open the otf and/or sfd files and merge/copy/create missing glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

(updated in 2022)

I think this font is a kind of vector font belonging to the Hershey family.

Here is a set of TTF fonts that are based on the Hershey font https://github.com/yangcht/Hershey_font_TTF.

You can download them and load them when you make plots.

[image]

[image]